# What could be a better naming convention for the variable 'completeConfig'?

Tags: naming, coding-standards, naming-standards

I have a feature in which the user can directly provide the entire nginx config inside the completeConfig variable in the config yaml.

Like this:

```
nginxConfig:
  completeConfig: >
   ....
   ....
```

But `completeConfig` variable seems a little weird. Can someone suggest something better?

Comment: Why is `completeConfig` present at all? It would feel natural if the (complete) nginx configuration were under `nginxConfig` without an additional layer.

Comment: We are providing default configs which works for most of the teams with options provided but if someone needs custom config, then we provide the option to drop in the entire config as well.

Comment: In the regular case (using your defaults), is the consumer giving you *overrides* that are merged into the nginx config, or are they setting some parameters which *you* have provided and will use to construct the config? In other words, is the default case just an incomplete nginx config, or is it a different structure entirely?

Comment: The default nginx config is the one that most of the teams will be using (an out of the box solution). They can set some optional parameters which, if they provide, will override the default ones. However, if you are completely deviating from the existing config and need something custom for your team then we have this option to provide the entire config

Comment: So the optional parameters have the same structure as a real ngingx config, except that they are optional?

Comment: Have you thought of simply calling it `custom`? As in place your `custom` config here? If its a template you could call it `template`. its pretty clear we are discussing the nginx config by dint of being under nginx in a configuration context.

Comment: I think `custom` sounds better than the `completeConfig` but it doesn't intuitively tells that this is where the users should add the entire nginx config.

Comment: @JacobRaihle we have a default nginx config where users can provide additional configs like `worker_processes` and `worker_conn` but it has a standard set of values. If you want to add more configs like epoll or proxy_cache that is not provided by default. In that case, users have to provide an entire config on their own

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is indeed somewhat special, many config systems would only support overrides of defaults, but not complete "deletion". In many cases, you have a cascade of defaults, i.e. there are default values defined in the software which can be overridden in the system installation, which can in turn be overridden in individual use cases.

Given your additional explanation, I'd use a `useDefaults: false` flag so that the actual config values are on the same level as when the defaults are used.

Comment: Right so I am just checking if the user provides the entire nginx config as part of `completeConfig`. If yes, I use that directly and skip all the other parts for the nginx config which were part of the default configs.